# Insert value with JS

Tags: javascript, events

I have following html:

```
<div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 text-center">
<input name="flash_price" type="hidden" id="test" value="">
<input name="from" type="hidden" value="">
<input name="to" type="hidden" value="">
<button type="button" id="my" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="<div class='form-group row'><label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Price<span class='text-danger'>*</span></label><div class='col-md-8 col-lg-10'><input name='special_price' type='text' class='form-control'></div></div><p>This product shall be displayed on the Flash sale. Creating flash sales increases the chance of product being sold.</p><div class='form-group row'> <label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>From<span class='text-danger'>*</span></label> <div class='col-md-8 col-lg-10'> <input name='starting_date' type='datetime-local' class='form-control' required value></div></div><div class='form-group row'><label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>To<span class='text-danger'>*</span></label> <div class='col-md-8 col-lg-10'> <input name='ending_date' type='datetime-local' class='form-control' required value></div></div><a id='optBtn' class='btn btn-primary input-group-addon'>OK</a>" title="" data-html="true" data-original-title="Flash Sales Price" aria-describedby="popover917523"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
</div>
```

I am trying to add value with js like this:

```
$(this).parent('col-md-1').find('input[name=flash_price]').attr('value', 'test value);
```

But when I try to do `$(this).parent('col-md-1').find('input[name=flash_price]').attr('id');` it says undefined. What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: What exactly says “undefined”…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your js to this
`$(this).parent('.col-md-1').find('input[name ="flash_price"]').val('test value');`

Comment: I tried this before but I think I made some mistake there. This worked for me.